# RavenDb backup using HTTP API and multi-tenancy

Tags: backup, ravendb

RavenDb Documentation shows how to backup a RavenDb database using

curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/admin/backup -d "{ 'BackupLocation': 'C:\Backups\2010-05-06' }"

But how can I backup a specific database using the HTTP API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tennants just become a sub-uri, so it would be http://localhost:8080/[TENNANT]/admin/backup

Personally I would use smuggler or rely on shadow copies.

Comment: Using the smuggler api it works like a charme, thx. Why do you prefer smuggler (beside it simply works). Whats the difference between the dumps compared to a backup?

Comment: Well, my windows servers don't have CURL avaliable in all cases to start with. AFAIK, smuggler is a nice .exe wrapper around that HTTP API. Personally I like shadow volume copies better, at least for DR type activity.

Comment: In my current scenario (alpha/beta state) I need to implement a temporary "backup" button on a website. Later on it is likely that it is hosted on RavenHQ where backup is simply part of the game. Thanks again.